# Proving a number is irrational by inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My professor gave us $\sqrt[10]{17}$, and asked us to prove its irrationality by inequality. They represented it as a polynomial function of $x$, $$x^{10}-17=0$$ Then said since $1<17<2^{10}$, then $1<\sqrt[10]{17}<2$. Since the middle term cannot be an integer between 1 and 2, then it must be irrational (I'm paraphrasing here, I might have gotten the reasoning wrong).

Can anyone describe how this works? If $x\in \mathbb Z$ then why does this work given that not every rational number is an integer?

Comment: Cf. [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Comment: Great question.  The reason $\sqrt[10]{17}$ must be irrational is that it's a non-integer root of a *monic* polynomial (that is, the coefficient of the leading term is $1$).  The "monic" restriction is required.... as you note, every rational $p/q$ is a polynomial root (of $qx-p=0$).

Comment: I think your professor may be relying on a theorem that says the $n$th root of an integer is either an integer or  is irrational, for integer $n \ge 2$.